# Accessing MySQL built-in functions using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

If I have a MySQL statement like this:

```
$sql="SELECT `name`, DATE(`time`), FROM `students` WHERE `id`='5'";
```

I am using CodeIgniter and trying to fetch the result in object format rather than array format (i.e. not using row_array())

```
$query=$db1->query($sql);
$row=$query->row();
```

I can get the name as

```
echo $row->name;
```

I cannot get the value of date with this method.

Any Ideas how I can get the date with this method, with something like:

```
echo $row->date;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your own field names in SQL like so:

```
$sql="SELECT `name`, DATE(`time`) as mydate, FROM `students` WHERE `id`='5'";
```

and subsequently access it like

```
echo $row->mydate;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But can if I want to protect it, should I use it with quotes,double-quotes or backticks?

Comment: If you look for a way to prevent bad userdata in your SQL queries look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797613/sql-injection-and-codeigniter or google.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the column in the result set to be named date, then add `AS date` after the `DATE` expression. You'll then be able to access it as `$row->date`.